# Designing Normalized Database in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, normalization

I am a novice database admin and I am working on a project that would take a hardware inventory spreadsheet and migrate it to SQL server. Currently, the data exists as one large denormalized view. I am trying to achieve 3NF, but somehow I feel that I haven't designed it well.

Let me give you a brief overview of the situation:

- The school district has several buildings, which in turn, have several rooms. The school is experiencing an expansionary period so new rooms are constantly "built", so the "Room Num" cannot be used as a primary key, therefore leading me to use a surrogate key.
- Teachers are assigned to rooms, but a room doesn't necessarily have to have a teacher (i.e. labs). Teachers can also change rooms.
- When the hardware is purchased, it is given a barcode number (think of it as a line item number on the PO). The actual piece of hardware is identified via its serial number.
- Hardware is assigned to a room and given a workstation number and assigned an IP address.

Does the design seem solid or is it flawed? Also, is it ok to create a junction table between a one-to-many relationship (a specific piece of hardware is assigned to a room, a room can have many pieces of hardware).

Please find the link below.

[Logical Database Design](http://sdrv.ms/12MaUZQ)

Comment: Looks solid to me, try to think of scenarios that would cause an issue, or things you might be asked to account for that aren't explicitly in the scope of your project (ie: when hardware is being repaired does it get assigned to a 'repair' room, or should there be a separate table for tracking repairs?) I agree that Hardware could be subdivided, whether it's worth going full 3NF or not depends on your data.

Comment: Thanks Goat_CO. There is a scenario in which the hardware is recycled, or otherwise deemed obsolete. At this point, the hardware is removed from the classroom and sent to a designated recycling area. In order for that to work, I would need an EndDate field in my hardware_room junction table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a functional decomposition of each entity and define what it "is" versus how it is used. 3NF is about avoiding duplication and keeping the right level of references.

For this problem, model a BUILDING (PK: auto-ID, name, etc).
Then model ROOM (PK: auto-ID, number, etc) with foreign-key to BUILDING primary key.
Then model TEACHER (PK: auto-ID, name, etc) with no foreign-keys.

For the relationship between teacher and room assignment, use a join table:

TEACHER_ROOM

This would have a compound primary-key of:
TEACHER_ID
ROOM_ID

Thus a teacher can be assigned to a room but a room does not need a teacher and in this model a teacher could be assigned to MANY rooms (one-to-many cardinality).

Same thing with hardware - define it by itself with SERIAL_NUMBER, etc.
Then have a ROOM_HARDWARE table that has which hardware is in which room with a unique key on the HARDWARE ID as it can only be in one room at a time but a ROOM can have many pieces of HARDWARE.

Comment: Thanks Darrell! Based on your feedback, I was on the right path, but I needed to flesh out a few items.

Comment: You are welcome. Most system design problems stem from data and object modeling so getting this right both early in your career and each project is critical to success in both. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The only one that sticks out to me is the Hardware table.  Category and Manufacturer should be in separate tables.

Comment: Thanks Chris, putting the manufacturer is something I should consider, given that people may enter HP as Hewlett Packard, Hewlett-Packard, or simply HP.